# Can't generate with package faker

Tags: python

I have some problem with generating fake cities and not only with cities.

```
from faker import Faker
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint

fake = Faker('en_US')
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

user_details = defaultdict(dict)
list_user_details = []

for i in range(0, 3):
    user_details["first_name"] = fake.first_name()
    user_details["address"]["city"] = fake.city()
    list_user_details.append(user_details.copy())

pp.pprint(list_user_details)
```

Output:

```
[   defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
                {   'address': {'city': 'Alanbury'},
                    'first_name': 'Jennifer'}),
    defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
                {   'address': {'city': 'Alanbury'},
                    'first_name': 'Bobby'}),
    defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
                {   'address': {'city': 'Alanbury'},
                    'first_name': 'Christopher'})]
```

The problem is that I can't receive a different city. But I didn't have a problem with first_name for example

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that address is a dict (mutable) while first_name is a string (immutable).

When you copy a dict that contains a mutable type (like another dict or a list) you make a **shallow** copy by default, that means you really only have one dict you keep overwriting, hence what you see here, immutable data types don't have this problem. In situation like that you have to use a **deepcopy**. For more details : https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html

However in your case using deepcopy would make your code unneccessary complicated I think, you can just write this.

```
for _ in range(3):
    user_details = { "address": { "city": fake.city() }, "first_name": fake.first_name() }
    list_user_details.append( user_details )
```